# Save each line as separate .txt file

Tags: notepad++

How in notepad do I save as such

Filename: Original.txt:

```
soandso@hotmail.com
emailnumber2@hotmail.com
emailnumber3@hotmail.com
```

--With Your Help--

Filename: 1.txt

```
soandso@hotmail.com
```

Filename: 2.txt

```
emailnumber2@hotmail.com
```

Filename: 3.txt

```
emailnumber3@hotmail.com
```

Answer (score 5):

I would write a simple [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) script for this:

```
$counter = 1

Get-Content "myfile.txt" | foreach {
    Set-Content -Path "$counter.txt" -Value $_
    $counter++
}
```

I don't know of any notepad++ specific solution as I don't use it, but I bet there's a way to [run PowerShell scripts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx#EBAA) from any good programmer-friendly text editor.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any notepad++ plugins or anything, but that is about 4-10 lines of code in Python or most other languages.

Loop:,
Make new txt file,
paste line

Next line, repeat.

Is there a particular reason you want it to be Notepad++ specific?

Edit:

I was intrigued by this idea so I went ahead and wrote it.

```
yourfile = open('YOUR.TXT', 'r')
counter = 0
magic = yourfile.readlines()

for i in magic:
    counter += 1
    newfile = open(('EMAILS' + str(counter) + '.TXT'), "w")
    newfile.write(i)
    newfile.close()
```

Unfortunately I don't know any .NET languages, but if you could write this in VBasic you could make this a macro in Notepad++ if its something you do regularly.

Comment: Perfect.
I know nothing about programming so I had to learn what the hell Python is. I found out you can save a .py in notepad++ so I went ahead and did that. Then I had to figure out how to execute a .py so I downloaded py2exe.  I then installed a .msi of Python 2.6 which is the only version compatible with that program. I replaced YOUR.TXT with the name of my text file, removed EMAILS so that they would simply be called 1.txt, 2.txt, etc and stuck my YOUR.TXT in the same folder as my .py. Bingo. It was an adventure but well worth it. Thank you for your time in helping me out.

Comment: Haha you're very welcome. I made those caps so you would see them and fix them as you pleased. Your implementation was much better than what I was thinking.

Comment: Also can you mark the response you favored best response please?